# Read sensor data from ThingSpeak with MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, iot, app-inventor, nodemcu, thingsboard

I've been trying to build an android IOT app using MIT App Inventor. It's supposed to read the voltage value from my NodeMCU device and display it. I think the values should be transmitted to ThingSpeak database channels and I did that just fine. But I can't find one single tutorial on how to read back the values in ThingSpeak on my Android application in all the articles about Bluetooth communication between Arduino and the smartphone, I was wondering how to do that with internet connection. I need a simple example on how to send a sensor data to ThingSpeak and show it on my android application..

Comment: you might want to try a search in the App Inventor forum like this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/thingspeak%7Csort:date or ask there...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.instructables.com/id/IoT-Made-Easy-With-UNO-ESP-01-ThingSpeak-and-MIT-A/

this is by far the best tutorial I've found to build an app around thingspeak data and arduino wifi

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.